# Creation of Kubernetes Cluster And Managment of Kubernetes resources in the same Terraform plan

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I Have the following issue as such - It could be just miss information - but i've been looking everywhere
and cant seem to find a clear answer on this

**So i'm looking to create a Kubernetes Cluster and then deploy some applications to it In the SAME TERRAFORM plan!.**

Issue is that terraform can't verify IAC with the cluster because it's not present yet..

I tried the Following:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_name
  
  depends_on = [
    module.EKS-create-cluster
  ]
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks_cluster_auth" {
  name = var.cluster_name

  depends_on = [
    module.EKS-create-cluster
  ]
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks_cluster_auth.token
}
```

**This Fails with the following**

```
 Error: Failed to construct REST client
│
│   with module.EKS-extensions.kubernetes_manifest.customresourcedefinition_operatorconfigs_monitoring_googleapis_com,
│   on modules/EKS-extensions/gcp-monitoring-setup.tf line 1103, in resource "kubernetes_manifest" "customresourcedefinition_operatorconfigs_monitoring_googleapis_com":
│ 1103: resource "kubernetes_manifest" "customresourcedefinition_operatorconfigs_monitoring_googleapis_com" {
│
│ cannot create REST client: no client config
```

**My Workaround is as follows:**

1: i have two separate plans one provision the cluster

2: The second Using data retrieves creds of the Cluster and loads it into the Kubernetes provider

Then with running -target= i'm able to deploy Kubernetes some manifests ...

**My Questions is as follows:**

(Keep in mind Kubernetes is referring to AWS's EKS)

Can i create a Kubernetes cluster and load it into the provider in the Same terrafrom plan?

Comment: This is only possible if you lock the Kubernetes provider to no higher than version 2.3.2. If that is ok, then this can be answered. Otherwise, this is not possible.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you please elaborate more on that?

why is that ?
and if you could please provider an example :)

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Please check [this part of provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/alpha-manifest-migration-guide#mixing-kubernetes_manifest-with-other-kubernetes_-resources). Interesting that this is not a problem for the helm provider, which effectively also applies manifest by the result.

Theoretically, while kubernetes manifest is a declarative resource, it should always be the same plan, especially when applying it to a new cluster, so plan is not really needed. But it's up to the provider architect's decision.

So variants are:

- use local-exec instead of kubernetes_manifest
- apply cluster first with target flag
- use separate states

Answer (score 0):

It seems, Terraform is not able to support such scenarios as of now (Jul 2023). There are 2 options to workaround this with additional tools:

1. Use Helm provider that supports dynamic configuration in scope of the same TF module which is working for some reason.
2. Use additional Terraform tools (Terragrunt, Terraspace) where you have a base K8s cluster module and dependant Kubernetes workloads.

In my case, I use the following structure on my projects (Terraspace example):

```
app
 + modules
    + aks-cluster
    + keycloak-operator
    + keycloak-cluster
    + grafana-operator
    + grafana-cluster
 + stacks
    + kubernetes      # Step 1. Setup aks-cluster module
    + kubernetes-base # Step 2. Setup all operators in K8s
    + grafana         # Step 3. Setup Grafana in K8s
    + keycloak        # Step 3. Setup Keycloak in K8s
```